# Why do we use interrogative pattern in "So was I"?

Tags: word-order

One of the examples I can mention is in *Captain America: Civil War*:

> **Captain America**: I was your friend.
>
> **Iron Man**: So was I.

Why did Iron Man use an interrogative pattern (verb before subject) while he used a period at the end; while he wanted to just tell him I was your friend too? Why not **so I was** for example?

Comment: That is **not** an interrogative pattern. If you start with a wrong assumption, you'll never find an answer.

Comment: @JohnLawler You are wrong. Many questions have wrong assumptions. But after receiving answers the asker begins to think the assumption was wrong. They begin to accept the answer as I did in comments.

Comment: That's the official ideal. The reality is something different. People are hard to convince they're wrong.

Comment: With this sentence: "People are hard to convince they're wrong" are you trying to say we should discourage people from asking questions based on wrong assumptions? That's not good at all. Remember what a great man once said: "Not knowing is not a fault. Not asking is a fault."

Comment: And also, it's our duty to provide answers whether the assumption of the question is correct or incorrect. It's our duty to provide answers whether the OP convinces or not. It's not our duty to convince anybody. We try, but it's not a duty.

Comment: Ptolemy's assumptions regarding the solar system were plain wrong. But it was those wrong assumptions that moved future people to think more and find a correct model.

Comment: A question is bad when the OP deliberately uses a wrong assumption. But if they don't know the matter and because of that they have a wrong assumption that's not a fault. And even that can be considered a good question. You should know this better than me.

Comment: Another great saying: "One who asks *looks* stupid for five minutes. One who doesn't ask (for any reason) *remains* stupid for their entire life."

Comment: @SnackExchange "So I was" and "so was I" have different meanings. Try taking that on board.

Comment: @BillJ I tried and I took that on board. Try looking at the comments on the answer.

Comment: @SnackExchange I think you're making heavy weather of a very simple point of grammar. If you can't grasp it, you should probably not be asking questions here, a site intended for those with a good knowledge of English grammar. FYI, "so" happens to be one of the words that triggers subject-aux inversion.

Comment: A note to all learners who think English is a SVO language only: So was I. Neither was he. Here comes the sun. No sooner had they begun their journey than it started to snow. Beside the table stood a chair. Hardly had she opened her mouth, when he entered the room. Above the chimneys and roofs flew Santa Claus. In the cellar lived a spider. 'What's the problem?', asked Jane.

Comment: @BillyKerr SVO is the correct term for English since it's the order that occurs in canonical clauses, which is the determining factor. Elsewhere, such as in clauses falling within the information packing domain, things are different, but that doesn't mean it's not an SVO language.

Comment: @BillJ I think he didn't say English isn't an SVO language.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think *an* SVO language is correct.

Comment: @SnackExhcange - oh yes, English is considered an SVO language generally, but everything doesn't always follow that word order. There are a few exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

It is a special use of ***so*** as a substitute. (By the way, other words know such usage, as for example *neither* or *nor*). [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so) explains:

> **So am I, so do I, Neither do I**
> We use ***so*** with be and with modal and auxiliary verbs to mean ‘***in the same way***’, ‘***as well***’ or ‘***too***’. We use it in order to *avoid repeating a verb, especially in short responses with pronoun subjects*. When we use so in this way, ***we invert the verb and subject, and we do not repeat the main verb***
>
> - **so + verb [= v] + subject [= s]**:
> - Geoff is a very good long-distance runner and ***so*** [V] ***is*** [S] his wife.
> - A: I’ve got loads of exam marking to do and I’m staying at home.
>   B: ***So*** [V] ***am*** [S] ***I***.

Note that the normal word order would be

> ***I was so** [meaning your friend].*
>  (not ***so*** *[your friend]* ***I was***).

Comment: I still can't get something. What's wrong with **I was so** that we use **So was I**? As you said we use the latter to avoid repeating the verb. But here *was* is the verb and it shows up in both sentences.

Comment: So replaces "your friend" in your example. It is just how English works in this context. Putting _so_ at the beginning of a sentence with this meaning demands SV inversion.

Comment: I figured it out. I just can't understand why it is not okay to say **I was so** in my example while in the second setence the verb gets repeated.

Comment: Also, in your last example, why is it not okay to say **I am so** while the verb *to stay* isn't repeated?

Comment: "I was so" sounds like an incomplete sentence, and "so" seems to be an intensifier of a missing adjective. If you want it to mean "the same, also, too", **so** goes at the beginning of the sentence and is used with inversion.

Comment: You could say, _I am also_ or _I am, too_, but _I am so_ does not have this meaning in English.

Comment: Your mentioning of missing object had a great point. Thanks.

Comment: "I was *so*" with emphasis on **so** means *au contraire*.  "You weren't at the game. -- I was so. I was sitting up at the top row of the bleachers."

Comment: "Ah, now I remember seeing you. So you were."

Comment: This is actually a rare vestige of V2 word order in English, which is much more common in other Germanic languages. It was much more common in the past. and survives only in a few modern constructions. E.g., "So was I", "Here comes the sun", "Here comes the bus", "Neither do I", "No sooner had he arrived . . . " etc. You can find many more examples in the King James Bible: "And God called the dry land Earth; and the gathering together of the waters **called he** Seas", "and the rib, which the LORD God had taken from man, **made he** a woman"

Answer (score -1):

The less-common pattern of ADV + V + PRON here is simply idiomatic in this type of expression. Though fairly rare now, it was more common in earlier use.

The pattern is used repeatedly in [Keats’s poem *On First Looking into Chapman's Homer*](https://poets.org/poem/first-looking-chapmans-homer), the first line of which is “Much have I traveled in the realms of gold.” And consider the fairly famous palindrome “Able was I ere I saw Elba.” (Admittedly that one is a bit contrived, precisely to make it palindromic.)